# Activating web feature from event receiver doesn't do anything

Tags: 2013, development, feature-activation, feature-receiver

I have the following code that should run to automatically disable the Minimal Download Strategy feature when a new site is being provisioned. Unfortunately nothing happens. No errors are captured in logs, and nothing is output to an exception file:

```
    public override void WebProvisioned(SPWebEventProperties properties)
    {
        //base.WebProvisioned(properties);
        using(SPWeb web = properties.Web)
        {
            try
            {
                Guid mdsGuid = new Guid("87294c72-f260-42f3-a41b-981a2ffce37a");
                // also tried with SPFeature
                SPFeatureCollection mdsFeature = web.Features;

                if (mdsFeature[mdsGuid] != null)
                {
                    // tried this with .Remove(mdsGuid, false) as well
                    web.Features.Remove(mdsGuid);
                    web.Update();
                }

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("s:\\exceptions\\fail-" + DateTime.Today + ".txt", false))
                {
                    file.WriteLine(ex);
                    file.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Any ideas why this *wouldn't* run?

Comment: Does it definitely hit the web.update()?

Comment: Yeah it hits web.Update() but nothing happens.

Comment: I'll test your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and it couldn't find that feature with the provided Guid. So I set this property and it worked:

```
web.EnableMinimalDownload = false;
web.Update()
```

Comment: Do you need to call web.Update() after or does it work with just that?

Comment: Yes. Always call update() or your changes will not be committed

Comment: Trying it right now

Comment: Thanks Colbs. Just had to do 3 iisresets for it to kick in.

Comment: haha. 3rd time's a charm. yw

Comment: Tell me about it.